# How to remove a trailer (PRP RCT) from the sk_buff in a Linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux, networking, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to implement the Parallel Redundancy Protocol (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Redundancy_Protocol) as a Linux kernel module (version 6.2+). I have created a virtual network interface (prp0) which uses two physical Ethernet devices. Ethernet frames sent to this interface are appended with a Redundancy Control Trailer (RCT) of 6 bytes which contains a sequence number. This sequence number is used to discard duplicates.

The module must remove the RCT before forwarding the frame to the network layer using netif_rx(). The problem is with the removal. I am removing the RCT by calling skb_trim on the sk_buff that is received. When I do try to remove the RCT, the data is not received by the applications. When I comment out the part that skb_trim, the data is received properly, but the RCT is also consumed by the applications. The code for the removal is given below:

```
    skb_trim(skb, skb->len - 6);
    clone_skb = skb_clone(skb, GFP_ATOMIC);
    if (!clone_skb) {
        pr_warn("%s: skb_clone returned NULL, not forwarding\n", __func__);
        return;
    }

    /* Remove Ethernet header */
    skb_pull(clone_skb, ETH_HLEN);
    len = clone_skb->len;
    res = netif_rx(clone_skb);
    if (res == NET_RX_DROP)
        pr_warn("%s:%s: netif_rx DROPPED\n", __func__, dev->name);
```

One thing I noticed with wireshark is that the IP header length is different for the frame received over the two networks. The second network has an IP payload length of 6 bytes more than the first one. I do not know what to make of this though. Could the problem be in the transmission side? But the frames are the same when viewed in wireshark. Only difference is the IP payload length. This difference is seen only at the receiver side; for the sender, both the frames have the same IP length.

So, I checked the frame using wireshark at both the sender and the receiver by capturing on the prp0 interface. At the sender side, the IP total length field is correct. But at the receiver the IP total length field is greater by 6 bytes. I do not understand how the IP header is being changed. I have modified the two slave devices to send the frames received to the receive handler for the PRP interface. The code is shown below:

```
    struct net_device *prp;
    int res;

    /* To listen to PRP supervision frames; TODO: sub to mcast */
    res = dev_set_promiscuity(slave, 1);
    if (res)
        return res;

    prp = port->master;
    res = netdev_upper_dev_link(slave, prp, extack);
    if (res) {
        NL_SET_ERR_MSG_MOD(extack, "Failed to link slave with master");
        printk(KERN_ERR "%s: failed to link with upper dev", __func__);
        goto fail_upper_dev_link;
    }

    res = netdev_rx_handler_register(slave, prp_recv_frame, port);
    if (res) {
        NL_SET_ERR_MSG_MOD(extack, "Failed to register rx handler");
        printk(KERN_ERR "%s: failed to register rx handler", __func__);
        goto fail_rx_handler;
    }

    /* LRO combines several frames together. This can affect PRP, since the
     * RCT will be incorrect.
     */
    dev_disable_lro(slave);

    return 0;

fail_rx_handler:
    netdev_upper_dev_unlink(slave, prp);
fail_upper_dev_link:
    dev_set_promiscuity(slave, -1);
    return res;
```

Looking at the `ip_rcv_core`  function in the kernel, I am guessing the datagram is being dropped due to the "bogus length". The IP header is the same on both the frames at the sender side, while inspecting the frames through the PRP interface and the two slave interfaces (can see the RCT in the slave interfaces, but not in PRP). But this is changed in the receiver side. Where could this change be occurring?

I have used the HSR module from the Linux kernel as a reference for implementing this which also implements PRP along with HSR. From what I can see, the HSR module also does the same, maybe I am missing something. (This is for a project I am doing as part of my course)

The entire source code for the module is available at: https://www.github.com/ramv33/prp